# Highlight "related sites" in the new /about page

Tags: feature-request, tour

One element the new `/about` page lacks is a place to highlight specific sister sites that user might be interested in.  For example, someone looking at Stack Overflow's `/about` to see if they should ask a database architecture question may not know that [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) exists.

I think the logical place for this would be the bottom of the About page, something like this:

[image]

This could be populated automatically (using the broad categories of Technology, Culture, Recreation, etc.), but I think it would be better to have the communities/mods select related sites to highlight by listing their URLs, similar to the way sites onebox in chat.
For sanity's sake I would limit this to 4 or 5 sites.

This is really more relevant to the technology (SO/SF/SU/Security/DBA/Apple/AskUbuntu/etc.) sites, but the list could simply be left blank for sites that aren't "strongly related" to others on the network.

Comment: Once useful limit may be to only refer sites that are out of beta.

Comment: @Some The language beta sites sometimes have questions that are split with Linguistics or some of the other cultural sites (all of which are also in beta).  If the mods can pick the sites, then they can use their best judgment whether to include beta sites or not, I think.

Comment: I don't think public betas should be excluded from the highlights list - it's a good way to drive (hopefully high-quality) traffic to them and raise awareness of their existence.